# Shapefile not displaying points (vertices) in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, display, vertices

this code finds all the vertices of every census tract for the state of California and Colorado. The code runs, and creates a shapefile with all proper filled fields (totpop, XCoord,YCoord, area1 etc.). 
The problem now is that nothing is displaying when I add the shapefile on ArcMAP, however, when I open the attribute table, all the fields are filled.

```
fp = r"C:\Users\mr276170\Desktop\EXPLOSION!"

import os
import arcpy
import math
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = fp

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#########
equal_shapeIN = fp + r'\CAandCO.shp'
out_shp = fp + r'\TheVertsAREAPOP.shp'
geometry_type = "POINT"
has_m = "DISABLED"
has_z = "DISABLED"

projection = arcpy.SpatialReference('USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic USGS')

arcpy.Project_management(equal_shapeIN, out_shp, projection)

#########                 

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(equal_shapeIN, out_shp)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(fp, 'TheVertsAREAPOP.shp',geometry_type, 'CAandCO.shp',has_m,has_z,projection)

dropFields = ["romney12", "obama12", "t_area", "totarea", "total_area"]

arcpy.DeleteField_management(out_shp,dropFields )

arcpy.DeleteRows_management(out_shp)

#########

fields = [('XCoord',"DOUBLE"), ("YCoord","DOUBLE"), ("area1","DOUBLE")]
for fields in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(*(out_shp,) +fields)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(equal_shapeIN,["OID@", "SHAPE@", "STATE_NAME", "NAME", "totpop", "POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER","SHAPE@AREA"]) as cursor:
    #####add area

    totalPOP = 0
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))

        partnum = 0
        for part in row[1]:
            print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
            for pnt in part:
                if pnt:
                    Xcoord = ("{}".format(pnt.X))
                    Ycoord = ("{}".format(pnt.Y))
                    stateNAME = row[2]
                    countyname = row[3]
                    totalPOP = row[4]
                    idpoly = row[5]
                    idobject = row[6]
                    stateFIPS = row[7]
                    countyFIPS = row[8]
                    fips = row[9]
                    fipSnum = row[10]
                    fipsNumer = row[11]
                    totarea = row[12]

                    print Xcoord, Ycoord, stateNAME, countyname, totalPOP, idpoly, idobject, stateFIPS, countyFIPS, totarea

                    cursor1 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_shp,["XCoord","YCoord","STATE_NAME", "NAME", "totpop", "POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER","area1"])
                               cursor1.insertRow([Xcoord,Ycoord,stateNAME,countyname,totalPOP, idpoly, idobject, stateFIPS, countyFIPS, fips, fipSnum, fipsNumer, totarea])

del cursor, cursor1

print "this works yo!"
```

Comment: The `del cursor` isn't necessary because the `with` does cleanup.  Your UpdateCursor doesn't ever update.  Please make sure your code samples are *minimal* -- see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Insert Cursor field list is adding attributes only. You need to include `SHAPE@XY` in your field list, and pass the XCoord and YCoord info to them:

```
cursor1 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_shp,["SHAPE@XY", "XCoord", "YCoord", "STATE_NAME", "NAME", "totpop", "POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER","area1"])
cursor1.insertRow([(XCoord, YCoord), Xcoord, Ycoord, stateNAME, countyname, totalPOP, idpoly, idobject, stateFIPS, countyFIPS, fips, fipSnum, fipsNumer, totarea])
```

This will pass your X & Y Coordinates to the `SHAPE` property of your feature, and not just as an attribute into `XCoord` and `YCoord` fields.